# Interpretation of multi-exponent x^y^z ($x^{y^z}$ or ${x^y}^z$)

Tags: exponentiation

**Is there any generally accepted or written rule specifying the interpretation of a multi-exponent expression written in this simple style (by user, no latex): `x^y^z`?**

It leads to different results on different engines: e.g. `5^2^3` can be interpreted as:

- **$5^{2^3}$ `$5^{2^3}$` = 390625**
- or as **${5^2}^3$ `${5^2}^3$` = 15625** (see that interpreted notation on Math StackExchange seems almost the same)

### Interpretation examples:

Interpretation of [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=5%5E2%5E3), [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5%5E2%5E3), [Bing](https://www.bing.com/search?q=5%5E2%5E3), [Yahoo](https://search.yahoo.com/search?p=5%5E2%5E3) is right associative: `$x^{y^z}$`

Interpretation of Windows Calculator / Samsung Calculator / Mac Spotlight is the second one (left associative): `${x^y}^z$` (equals to $x^{y \cdot z}$)

On my CASIO fx-85ES calculator when I click *[num] [pow] [num] [pow] [num]* result is the first one: `$x^{y^z}$`

Now I see on Math StackExchange that if I write `$x^y^z$` it will raise an error "Double exponent: use braces to clarify".
[image] However I do not know any other latex validator which will raise an error like this.

My observation so far shows that most search engines choose the first way `$x^{y^z}$` and most calculator apps choose the second way as sequential interpreting from left to right `$x^{y^z}$`.

Comment: No, no rule about it. $x^{y}^{z}$ is considered as bad notation.

Comment: In the last line you write the same thing as before.

Comment: It is interpreted as $x^{(y^z)}$ because, if you meant $(x^y)^z$, you might as well write $x^{yz}$ because that comes to the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Wikipedia [Operator associativity page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity): "...for an exponentiation operator (if present) [[source](https://codeplea.com/exponentiation-associativity-options)] and [Knuth's up-arrow operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation) **there is no general agreement**."

There is a list of implementations (right- vs left-associative) across computer languages, available in [the source](https://codeplea.com/exponentiation-associativity-options) that Wikipedia mentions.

Comparative table:

```
| Interpreter           |   | Expon. assoc.     |
|-----------------------|---|-------------------|
| Bash                  |   | Right-associative |
| Python                |   | Right-associative |
| Ruby                  |   | Right-associative |
| C++                   | ! | Left-associative  |
| -- Search engines: -------------------------- |
| Google, Bing, Yahoo   |   | Right-associative |
| WolframAlpha          |   | Right-associative |
| -- Spreadsheets: ---------------------------- |
| MS Excel              | ! | Left-associative  |
| Google Sheets         | ! | Right-associative |
| -- Other: ----------------------------------- |
| Matlab                | ! | Left-associative  |
| Windows, Samsung Calc.| ! | Left-associative  |
| Mac Spotlight         | ! | Left-associative  |
| Hand-held calculators | ! | Varies            |
                 ! means be careful
```

`x^y^z` can be also written as $x\uparrow y\uparrow z$. In both cases, the **interpretation is ambiguous**.

Because we can rewrite the statement after left-assoc. interpretation ${x^y}^z$ as $x^{y \cdot z}$ we can assume that this behavior is not what a regular user wants because he can write directly $x^{y \cdot z}$. From this point of view, it seems that right-associative approach is "better". I do not say more correct because we have no general rule/agreement for that.

There is also a **mnemonics** called [PEMDAS/BEDMAS/BODMAS/BIDMAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) (depends in countries). It calls us we should solve Brackets > Orders **(e.g. powers, square roots)** > Division > Multiplication > Addition > Subtraction. According to this mnemonics we should proceed from top to down for powers (**right-association**).

### Negation vs exponentiation

There is also one more important problem you can face in this context: **variable negation or exponentiation first**? [[source](https://codeplea.com/exponentiation-associativity-options)]

- **Negation first: $-2^2$ = 4**
- **Exponentiation first: $-2^2$ = -4**

Comparative table:

```
| Interpreter           |   | Neg. or Expon. first |
|-----------------------|---|----------------------|
| Bash                  | ! | Negation             |
| Python                |   | Exponentiation       |
| Ruby                  |   | Exponentiation       |
| -- Search engines: ----------------------------- |
| Google, Bing, Yahoo   |   | Exponentiation       |
| WolframAlpha          |   | Exponentiation       |
| -- Spreadsheets: ------------------------------- |
| MS Excel              | ! | Negation             |
| Google Sheets         | ! | Negation             |
| -- Other: -------------------------------------- |
| Matlab                |   | Exponentiation       |
| Hand-held calculators | ! | Varies               |
                 ! means be careful
```

### Conclusion

**However it seems that the right-associative approach has more logical bases, we do not have any official rule that says it is right/wrong approach.**

**So since you know that a definition of the notation is missing, you should always use braces (as StackExchange parser also recommends) to avoid unexpected results.**

Answer (score 1):

Well, exponentiation is right associative, i.e., $x\uparrow y\uparrow z$ means $x\uparrow (y\uparrow z)$, which equals $x^{(y^z)}$.

Comment: Do you have any source for that statement?

Comment: Its mentioned here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

$$(x^y)^z$$ is equivalent to $x^{yz}$ so there would be little point writing

$$x^{y^z}$$ which would have that meaning.